# I want to input data but this error pops up "Input 0 of layer "sequential'.........(None, 7, 7)"

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I encountered a problem when input my data for LSTM neural network. I have train the model for 7 number of features, normalize data, and more. But when I want to predict my data, the errors pops up.
Here's the code:

```
excel2 = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/DATA/data2.xlsx')

to_predict=np.array(excel2)
scaled_to_predict = scaler.transform(to_predict)

  scaled_prediction_output_1 = model.predict(np.array([scaled_to_predict]))
  print(scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_prediction_output_1).astype(int)[0])
```

and  here's the picture of my data
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS8Tf.png)

I'm try to reshape the data but it wont work

```
excel2 = pd.read_excel('/content/drive/MyDrive/DATA/data2.xlsx')

to_predict=np.array(excel2)
num_features = 7
sequence_length = 30
scaled_to_predict = scaler.transform(to_predict.reshape(1, -1, num_features))

scaled_prediction_output = model.predict(scaled_to_predict)


prediction_original = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_prediction_output).astype(int)[0]

print("Predicted Values:")
print(prediction_original)
```